# Fetch Lat Long from table and mark on google map

Tags: php

I'm using **php** and I want to fetch two columns from table like **Latitude** and **Longitutde** and add the ***markers*** on google map based on lat and long values, how i do..

Answer (score -1):

After you get latitude and longitude data,

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

API Key must be included

Comment: @Ozgur This is a rather javascript solution.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Is there a way to add marker on google map, using only php?

Comment: Please include this in the answer about that.

Comment: @Ozgur sir Thanku,

Comment: @Ozgur sir, but there is another problem like i get 6 rows from table and using this code it fetch last row(6th) lat,lng value and add on map but, i want to add all 6 rows lat,lng value on map

Comment: @TaranpreetSingh multiple markers example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example